# OrderByDescending in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I have a issue with OrderByDescending in Orchard CMS

Example Data:

```
ID        Name             DomainId
1          First              2
2          Join               3
3          Peter              1
4          Abert              1
5          saha               2
```

with LinQ to SQL code here:

> IQueryable().OrderByDescending(r=> r.DomainId == 2)

it returns the correct result !

```
ID        Name             DomainId
1          First              2
5          saha               2
2          Join               3
3          Peter              1
4          Abert              1
```

**but with OrchardCMS**

> IContentQuery().OrderByDescending(r=> r.DomainId == 2)

it returns the incorrect result and it will order from large to small

```
ID        Name             DomainId
2          Join               3
1          First              2
5          saha               2
3          Peter              1
4          Abert              1
```

**Why incorrect ? and how to fix**

Please help me!

---

i want to return results with sort by DomainId

Example: with DomainId = 2 => IContentQuery().OrderByDescending(r=> r.DomainId == 2)

```
ID        Name             DomainId
1          First              2
5          saha               2
2          Join               3
3          Peter              1
4          Abert              1
```

Example: with DomainId = 3 => IContentQuery().OrderByDescending(r=> r.DomainId == 3)

```
ID        Name             DomainId
2          Join               3
1          First              2
5          saha               2
3          Peter              1
4          Abert              1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:
    .OrderByDescending(r=> r.DomainId == 2 ? 1 : 0)

Comment: it returns the incorrect result and it will order from large to small, the same question above

Comment: Please enable the mini profiler, use it to get the SQL version of the order by, and paste it here.

Comment: pList.OrderByDescending(a => a.Domain.Id == 2) 
With Mini Profiler 
=> `DECLARE 'p0 INT = 20 ,'p1 BIT = 1 SELECT TOP ('p0) this_.Id AS Id65_3_ FROM Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord this_ LEFT OUTER JOIN ..... WHERE propertypa2_.Published = p1 ORDER BY propertypa2_.Domain_id DESC`

Comment: Seems like the Lambda-based mapping code isn't looking very far and thinks you want to order by Domain_Id. You may have to switch to writing a Hql query as text instead of using the high-level API. I wrote a series of posts on http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy about this, that should help.

Answer (score 0):

`IContentQuery().OrderByDescending(r=> r.DomainId)` is the right approach I think. The expression `(r=> r.DomainId == 2)` is it evaluate right result?